# Do Firebase listeners such as childEventListener download all data regardless of ui?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I am building a photo based app, and I m retrieving the photos from the data base with a childEventListener, and then add every child added to my recyclers adapter.

What I am trying to understand is, does the listener downloads all the data regardless of how many items the user has browsed through?

For example: in my data base I have 500,000 posts by users. I have a childEventistener that adds every child to my recycler's adapter.
On screen only 2 photos fit and the user has scrolled past 20 before leaving the app.

Did the data of all the 500,00 download to their phone? I'm wondering how to be the most efficient in my code so the user's data is not wasted for no reason.

Answer (score 2):

If you add a listener to a node in your database, it will download all the children under that node, and all of their children, and so on.

If this isn't what you want, then you should page the results using the methods that let you limit the number of children, and specify an offset to the child you want.  [Read the documentation for that](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data).